# Swift how to sign user out when app closes using Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

This is how users navigate through my app:

1. Enter a phone number
2. Enter verification number (This allows them access to my Firestore)
3. Enters a username
4. Now they're in the main app

Pretty straightforward however the problem is if the app crashes (for whatever reason) or closes when they are entering the username, they are still technically signed in to my Firestore.

It's a problem because I programmed the app such that when the user reopens the app, they immediately go to the main screen (I created an app manager to handle this). If they close the app (or if it crashes) before they enter a username, they can go right to the main screen without a username.

I've made several different attempts in the applicationWillTerminate method to track which view controller the user is in, sign out so that when the user open the app again, my App Manager says, Auth.auth().currentUser == nil and goes to the initial view controller to start the registration process again.

```
var viewController : UIViewController?
        var vc = UsernameViewController()

        if viewController == vc {

            let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
                        do {
                            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
                        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
                        }
```

I expect the user who did not get a chance to create a username because the app closed or crashed to to return to the initial view controller rather than the main screen of the app.

I am currently experiencing the opposite.

Comment: Did you consider detecting the incomplete user profile upon restart, and taking them to a screen that allows them to enter their user name? That seems like a better user experience, then having them restart from scratch.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I fixed the problem and was able to implement your idea. So what I did was, I have a blank view controller that dictates what screen my app should show. Within its class, I am getting realtime updates within : uniqueUsers/ { specific user uid } and I have two bool fields: one that checks if the phone number was created and another that checks if the username was created. I set a few if conditions to check user login status, username status etc.. and used storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleController") for each condition.

Comment: Just a tip.. I had everything working and then 5 minutes later, it seemed like all my problems came back. Turns out Google was down according to downdetector.com and my app couldn’t reach Firestore. It may be rare for this to happen to anyone viewing this but you never know.

Comment: A network outage started across many Google Cloud services around 11:50 am pacific time. It seems some services have been recovering since about 12:40 pm. Keep an eye out on the Firebase status page for updates: https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Will do; thank you for that link